# Blessing one's spouse on Shabbas

Tags: shabbat, blessing, marriage

Every Shabbas I bless my 3 children but I feel like it's incomplete. What about a blessing on for my wife?

I suppose many sing Eshet Chayil but I feel it is more directed to the Shabbas rather than my wife (even my wife will sing it).

What should one say to show gratitude towards one's wife, and ask for protection over her, as well as protection over our marriage?

Comment: Whatever you want whenever you want. Give everyone blessings all the time if you so desire.

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer.

Comment: Thank her, pray for her, pray for your marriage. Show affection, give appreciation, express your love.

Comment: Sure... But what blessing?

Comment: @Crudler you can use your own words, and even change from week to week. You can start with "May Hashem bless you with" or "May Hashem send you". Let your heart do the speaking !

Comment: @Crudler consider "may your hard boiled eggs always come out the right consistency" or "may you stub your toe fewer times"

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a *minhag* for the husband to bless his wife with the same blessing he gives his daughters.

I don't know if this *minhag* has a source, or if the Sephardic couple who used to eat by us invented it themselves - he would put his hands on her head and bless her, and she would then do the same to him. (Upon asking around, others had seen the same, although nobody could source it or attribute the custom to a specific category.)

Comment: Wouldn't this be an issue during *niddah* times?